# How to do an insert select with the select subquery returning multiple columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to insert into a table some values, and then the remaining values should come from a select subquery in Postgres, I've been stuck, I also need to reuse the code somewhere else
Please help me out. 
I'm having the error of `subquery must return only one column`. I want to return the three columns email, name, address

```
INSERT INTO
    books
      VALUES 
      ( 1, 2, 3, (SELECT email, name, address FROM users WHERE userID=1)) RETURNING *;
```

Comment: You have multiple users with userID = 1, maybe you need to clean up your database.

Comment: I don't think so. The user_id is the primary key

Comment: Why don't you check? Another way of writing that query is `INSERT INTO books SELECT 1, 2, 3, email, name, address FROM users WHERE userID = 1` which might be worth trying

Comment: but the values 1, 2, 3 are not in the table of users, will it work like that?

Comment: OMG!!!!!!!!!!!!!! It worked! I've spent the whole day on it! Thanks so much and God bless

Comment: It looks to me that the error message from PostgreSql was a little misleading here.

Comment: How do you select from a table if a condition is met and then left join another table if the same condition is met?

Answer (score 4):

Don't use the VALUES clause if your source for the INSERT is a SELECT:

```
INSERT INTO books
SELECT 1,2,3,email, name, address 
FROM users 
WHERE userID=1
RETURNING *;
```

Note that it's good coding style to explicitly list the columns of the target table: `insert into books (col1, col2, col3, ...)`

Comment: @Joakims answer already answered it but I'm really grateful as this is the same answer

Comment: I'm also trying to select everything from a table if a condition is met and then join it with another table if the same condition is met. How do I do that, I want some kind of LEFT JOIN. Thanks

Comment: @OkabaMac . . . New questions should be asked as *questions*, not in comments.

Answer (score -3):

```
SELECT `email` as f FROM users WHERE userID=1
union SELECT `name` as f FROM users WHERE userID=1
union SELECT `address` as f FROM users WHERE userID=1
```

Comment: The use of UNION here is completely pointless and will return multiple rows which is exactly _not_ what OP wants

Comment: Backticks around identifiers are invalid in (standard) SQL